# Is there any way to retrieve schema/containers structure from griddb?

Tags: griddb

Like in SQL Server/Postgres we are able to fetch complete schema information like this

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TAbles
```

I have read docs and references from griddb official [here](https://docs.griddb.net/about/what-is-griddb/)

Need to locate any information in which I will extract schema/containers information.

Answer (score 1):

in gs_sh try:

`showcontainer` or `showtable` to list all the containers or tables in the database

,and `showcontainer container_name` or `showtable table_name` to fetch its schema.